# Multi dimensional array from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create multidimensional array with `start_date` and `end_date` values

```
$array = [];
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[$i]['start_date'] = $row['current_status_start_time'];
    $array[$i]['end_date'] = '';
    $i++;
}
print_r($array);
```

This returns me array like this:

```
  Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
         [start_date] => 2013-07-25 11:18:42
         [end_date] => )
    [1] => Array (
         [start_date] => 2013-07-26 05:24:08
         [end_date] => )
    [2] => Array ( 
         [start_date] => 2013-07-31 17:25:05
         [end_date] => )
 )
```

`end_date` should get next array `[start_date]` node value:

```
        Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
         [start_date] => 2013-07-25 11:18:42
         [end_date] =>   **2013-07-26 05:24:08**)
    [1] => Array (
         [start_date] => **2013-07-26 05:24:08**
         [end_date] =>   2013-07-31 17:25:05)
    [2] => Array ( 
         [start_date] => 2013-07-31 17:25:05
         [end_date] => current_date)
 )
```

As you can see in the last code example, `array[0][end_date]` should get `array[1][start_date]` value and so on, the last array `end_date` should get current time value, because there is end of array.

Should I use second loop to achieve that? or there is alternative and more simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you what you want:

```
$array = [];
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[$i]['start_date'] = $row['current_status_start_time'];
    $array[$i]['end_date'] = '';
    if ($i > 0){
        // if we are pass the first item set the previous item to the current start date
        $array[$i-1]["end_date"] = $array[$i]['start_date'];
    }
    $i++;
}
// fill in the last end_date with the current_date
$array[$i]["end_date"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a loop.  Something like this:

```
foreach($mainArray as $key => $value)
{
    $next = $key + 1;

    if(!is_null($mainArray[$next]['start_date']))
    {
        $mainArray[$key]['end_date'] = $mainArray[$next]['start_date'];
    }
    else
    {
        $mainArray[$key]['end_date'] = current_date;
    }
}

print_r($main_array);
```